# what does the "data.frame$.variable" mean in a function?

Tags: r, function

I have seen a function:

```
smotest <- list(name = "SMOTE with more neighbors!",
            func = function (x, y) {
              library(DMwR)
              dat <- if (is.data.frame(x)) x else as.data.frame(x)
              dat$.y <- y
              dat <- SMOTE(.y ~ ., data = dat, k = 10)
              list(x = dat[, !grepl(".y", colnames(dat), fixed = TRUE)], 
                   y = dat$.y)
              },
            first = TRUE)
```

In this function, what does the`dat$.y`mean, eapecially the ".", and why it has a ".".

Comment: `.y` is the name of a column  (albeit a bad one) in the data frame `dat`, and `$`  is an extraction function. See `help("$")` for more.

Comment: The `.` may have come from reading a file with non-syntactical names.

Comment: thank you very much. I have tried it, the'.y' is really only the column name, but has no other meanings.